# A simple Regular expression that bothers me

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
<!--:en-->&nbsp;

<!--:-->
```

I want to construct a pattern to extract it from a string (PHP). I try with:

```
<!--:[a-z]{2}-->(&nbsp;\r\n\s)<!--:-->
```

But it does not work, does anybody know why or could help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You probably don't want to use regex to parse XML/HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

And that for a lot of [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg).

Instead usually you would prefer to parse with [tools made for this specific task](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).

---

Anyway, what you need here is more something like:

```
(&nbsp;|\s)*
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters, such as hyphen. Try this:

```
/<\!\-{2}\:[a-z]{2}\-\->((&nbsp;|\s)*)<\!\-{2}\:\-{2}>/
```

Comment: Be careful here you capture strings such as "ssspppsppps"

Comment: Thank you. I've emended my answer now to enforce &nbsp;

Comment: Now you capture the &nbsp; but only one can be detected.

Comment: Phew, encapsulated the whole thing in another group, which ought to include &nbsp; and white spaces. At this rate, however, I'm inclined to agree with you that regular expressions might not be the right course of action for this kind of thing - in PHP you can easily implement this functionality using strpos and an incrementing cursor.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question, you have to match the *entire* text, comments included.

So, strictly about your specific problem, I would use something like that:

```
$s = "<!--:en-->&nbsp; 

<!--:-->";

$a = array();
preg_match('/<!--:[a-z]{2}-->&nbsp;\\s+<!--:-->/', $s, $a);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++) {
  var_dump(htmlentities($a[$i]));
}
```

Generally, I do not question if you should parse HTML with regular expressions or not, but  notice, though, that Colin is right when he says that realistically parsing HTML with regular expressions can be *outstandingly* hard (read "nearly impossible"), as the posts he indicated state.